# IIS 8.0 Problems serving up huge static pages

Tags: iis-8

I have an internal IIS server that is used to serve static html pages located on a network share, mounted as a virtual directory.

Some of these static html pages are HUGE- I have seen a couple that were 50MB of html, with over 8000 embedded images.  These are auto-generated reports from a legacy system, I have no control over them at all.

Users are reporting problems with these pages loading.  And while I would fully expect them to load very slowly due to their size, what I am seeing are a lot of errors with the GET requests.

So for example, a 20MB html page may have 6000 images sitting back on the network share.  5500 load okay, 500 generate GET errors in Chrome Developer Tools.  Status failed, Type Pending, Initiator Parser (to be specific what I see on the Network tab of the tool).

If I copy the URL for one of those errors, and paste it directly into the browser, it pulls up the image just fine.

I think I'm running up against some performance bottleneck, but am unsure what to look for.

Suggestions?  Maybe tweaks to IIS?

Comment: What does your IIS error log say?

Comment: Actually, from your Chrome debug info, this sounds like a client-side problem, not a server-side problem, in which case, you need to re-architect how your client is fetching the page assets, possibly catching errors and retrying.

Comment: As far as I can tell there are no errors in IIS- but I've just been looking at the event log...